# Can't maven build project in Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 in windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, eclipse-rcp

Getting the below error in log

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test_art 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom (4 KB at 1.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom (13 KB at 11.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/21/maven-parent-21.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/21/maven-parent-21.pom (26 KB at 23.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/10/apache-10.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/10/apache-10.pom (15 KB at 13.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.712 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-04T15:55:38+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 (C:\Users\479848\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-clean-plugin\2.5\maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar): error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginDescriptorParsingException
```

Here getting the error Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: try deleting the data from repo folder and do clean install again

Answer (score 0):

Delete `C:\Users\479848\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-clean-plugin\2.5\ folder` and try again.

Maybe be the jar file is incomplete or corrupted.